# heatmaply + flexdashboard = Error in validateCssUnit(sizeInfo$width) : CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector

Tags: flexdashboard, heatmaply

````
---
title: heatmaply and flexdashboard don't mix...
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

### Chart 1
    
```{r}
library(heatmaply)
heatmaply(mtcars)
````

I saw this question (2018):

[R shiny error: Error in html tools::validateCssUnit(height); CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737864/r-shiny-error-error-in-html-toolsvalidatecssunitheight-css-units-must-be-a)

presumably they are related...

- Heatmaply is version: 1.1.1
- flexdashboard is version: 0.5.2

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this for code: `ggplotly(x)` which caused the error.

I added `ggplotly(x, height=500, width=1000)` and the error went away.